# Loop PCM file with a custom loop period using OpenAL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, openal

I'm trying to loop the source, that lasts for example 1 second, at the way, that the next loop will start in 4 seconds after the source ends. I see two ways to solve this.

1. Manually put «empty» butes in buffer, so source will be 4 seconds length.
2. Put some kind of timer.

Am I going to the right direction? Maybe there's simple ways to do this?

Killed whole day thinking of this task. Thanks!